# Why use @media (min-width: 992px + 1px) instead of @media (min-width: 993px) in Bootstrap

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4, media-queries, gulp-sass

In Bootstrap 4.1.3 it looks like some media queries are written as `@media (min-width: 992px + 1px)`.

This is not being rendered at all in my browser... (I'm compiling SASS) If I physically change that to: `@media (min-width: 993px)` in the compiled CSS, then everything works as it should. I would rather not edit the core Bootstrap SASS. Why isn't the `+1px` rendering, or how do I get this to work?

Thanks all for any input.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I have tried in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge. It was fine in edge, however Chrome and Firefox did not work.

Comment: How did you compile the source? I just compiled v4.1.3 and see no `+ 1px` in any media queries.

Comment: I'm compiling using gulp-sass. Perhaps I'm not doing something correctly in that process. Everything seems to compile fine except for those media queries.

Comment: This article is pretty similar to what I am doing: https://coursetro.com/posts/design/72/Installing-Bootstrap-4-Tutorial

Comment: I am also seeing a "@media (min-width: 768px + 1px)"

Comment: Thats the way I do mine, except I go a minus instead of plus. @media screen and (min-width: $tablet) and (max-width: $desktop - 1px)

Comment: Can you post your `gulpfile.js` contents since you're compiling with Gulp? I'm not certain the Gulp config is the issue though.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply to this. I found the problem which happened to be in a custom scss file (semicolon in wrong place), and it was causing my scss to not compile correctly. All is well now!

Comment: For other Googlers who arrive here - I had a similar problem. My issue was that the `+ 1px` was outside of the `#{}`. Moving it "inside" the curly braces fixed the problem. In other words, I changed `#{ ... } + 1px` to `#{ ... + 1px }`